# Attach file in MS Access using the path in the same record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have some experience in MS Access, but can't seem to find vba that attaches the file to the record. I only have about 2,000 records (no more since it's a data entry project) so MS Access db size won't be an issue.  Each record has the full path in a "path" field, but I can't figure out how to use vba to attach the file in a new "attachment" field.

Everything I've seen so far is about the user attaching a file or creating a path - not actually using the vba to attach the file (given that I already have the path).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.LoadFromFile` method of an Access `DAO.Field2` object. For example, given a table named [tblTest]

ID - AutoNumber, Primary Key
MyFilePath - Text(255)
MyFileAttach - Attachment

containing

```
ID  MyFilePath                      MyFileAttach
--  ------------------------------  ------------
1   C:\Users\Gord\Pictures\r.bmp    @(0)
2   C:\Users\Gord\Pictures\g.bmp    @(0)
3   C:\Users\Gord\Pictures\b.bmp    @(0)
```

the following code will insert the specified file into the [MyFileAttach] field for each record

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rstMain As DAO.Recordset, rstAttach As DAO.Recordset2, _
        fldAttach As DAO.Field2
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rstMain = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MyFilePath, MyFileAttach FROM tblTest", dbOpenDynaset)
Do Until rstMain.EOF
    rstMain.Edit
    Set rstAttach = rstMain("MyFileAttach").Value
    rstAttach.AddNew
    Set fldAttach = rstAttach.Fields("FileData")
    fldAttach.LoadFromFile rstMain("MyFilePath").Value
    rstAttach.Update
    rstAttach.Close
    Set rstAttach = Nothing
    rstMain.Update
    rstMain.MoveNext
Loop
rstMain.Close
Set rstMain = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
```