# Uploading attachments to MS Access database

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I am trying to upload files from a folder onto a Microsoft Access database, serially so as to upload every file in the folder to each of the attachments.

The closest I got to the result is having an error message that the file " 1.jpg" cannot be found, obviously because of the blank space put before the numbering with the string conversion. I proceeded to format the string with the remarks seen below in my program and got a different error message, that the command uploading the file needed an object, so that didn't work. What goes wrong with the two versions seen below?

```
Sub AttachPhotos()

Dim Filename As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = OpenDatabase("G:\My Drive\Takis\Graffiti.accdb")
Set Photo = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
Photo.Edit
Set Photos = Photo.Fields("Photo").Value

For i = 1 To 3486

Rem If i <= 9 Then
Rem Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(1, "0")) & ".jpg"
Rem ElseIf (i > 9) And (i <= 99) Then
Rem Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(2, "0")) & ".jpg"
Rem ElseIf (i > 99) And (i <= 999) Then
Rem Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(3, "0")) & ".jpg"
Rem ElseIf (i > 999) Then
Rem Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(4, "0")) & ".jpg"
Rem End If

Photos.AddNew
Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Str(i) & ".jpg"
Photos.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile (Filename)
Photos.Update
Photo.Update
Next

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set Photo = Nothing
Set Photos = Nothing

End Sub
```

```
Sub AttachPhotos()

Dim Filename As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = OpenDatabase("G:\My Drive\Takis\Graffiti.accdb")
Set Photo = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
Photo.Edit
Set Photos = Photo.Fields("Photo").Value

For i = 1 To 3486

If i <= 9 Then
Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(1, "0")) & ".jpg"
ElseIf (i > 9) And (i <= 99) Then
Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(2, "0")) & ".jpg"
ElseIf (i > 99) And (i <= 999) Then
Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(3, "0")) & ".jpg"
ElseIf (i > 999) Then
Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Format(i, String(4, "0")) & ".jpg"
End If

Photos.AddNew
Rem Filename = "G:\My Drive\Takis\SS_photendix\" & Str(i) & ".jpg"
Photos.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile(Filename).Value
Photos.Update
Photo.Update
Next

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set Photo = Nothing
Set Photos = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does Table1 have records?  All you're doing is loading a file into the same field of the first record (assuming there are records) each time the loop iterates...

Comment: You are aware that .accdb has a 2 GB file size limit? So if your pictures are on average larger than 600 kB (probably less because of overhead), this will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attach file in MS Access using the path in the same record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900625/attach-file-in-ms-access-using-the-path-in-the-same-record)

Comment: You are right, @TimWilliams, I have not populated the database with records yet, which I will soon do.

Comment: Yes, @HansUp , it brings out the same error message that object is required for the command that uploads the file, as the one it brings if the If statement is otherwise used.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help and advice, the second version of the program finally worked, and uploaded the first attachment to the first record, although the reason it stopped is because there were no more records after the first one as the database is not populated with the data yet.